# Is it anti-pattern to alter domain model on front end?

Tags: json, rest, oop, design-patterns, architecture

We are making a quiz application, I'm trying to integrate my Angular 2 UI with the REST api.

Our Quiz domain model consist of the following (simplified) hierarchy:

- Quiz
- Category
- Question
- Choice

where parent doesn't know it's children, but child knows it's parent. For example, Choice has a reference for a Question, but Question doesn't have reference to choice. We chose this approach to be able to fetch the quiz data more flexible and modular approach, also avoiding circular references.

However, in front end it's counter-intuitive to use inverted linking, as views are built naturally layer-by-layer iterating deeper in the domain object structure. It makes sense to render view for Question first, and render sub-view for Choices after. It just seems impossible with the current domain model, where I should start from Choice.

My question is, if it's common or approved to convert the domain model on the front end, so I wold gather all data and add Choice reference to Question afterwards, making the model compatible for top-down approach? And of course convert it back when POSTing to REST api.

Does this indicate bad design, or is it approved to alter the domain model?

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO. Perhaps you might try to ask some moderator to move it to [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It's not "convert domain model on front-end" because your front-end is not playing with domain model. It's playing with Data Transfer Object (json object returned from calling server API in this case). So feel free to do everything you want with DTO on client.